# How can I check if form is not empty and if form is empty then set disabled="disabled" into submit button?

Tags: jquery, forms

How can I check if form is not empty and if form is empty then set `disabled="disabled"` into submit button?

```
<form action="/contact/" method="POST" id="form">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail">
    <textarea name="msg" id="msg" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="button-contac-send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you how you could do it, then try to get it to work. If your struggling post your code here and we'll help out. You can do this using Jquery or adding Required Field validators to your textbox.

If your going down the JQuery route, on click of your submit button(you will need to give it an ID attribute first) check if those fields are all empty. If they are then you can say return false. And that will cancel the submit event.

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries & native APIS to handle client side validation that are worth leveraging

#### [HTML 5 Form Validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation)

You can use the `required` attribute in any input and the browser will block client side submits:

```html
<input id="name" name="name" required >
```

For more advanced handling, you can also wire up Javascript using the [Constraint Validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#The_HTML5_constraint_validation_API)

#### jQuery Validate

Another popular client side validation framework is the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

#### Custom JavaScript

If you want to write yourself... assuming all fields are required, you'll need to capture change events to all inputs, verify that all inputs have a value, and then conditionally toggle the disabled attribute on the submit button.  In jQuery, it would look something like this:

```js
// get all input elements and attach listener
var $inputs = $("#myForm :input:not([type='submit'])")
$inputs.change(function() {

  // check if all elements have value
  var allInputsHaveValue = $inputs.toArray().every(function(el) {
    return !!el.value
  });

  // toggle submit disabled
  $("#submit").prop("disabled", !allInputsHaveValue);

}).change(); // run on init
```

[**Demo in jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/R8c8h/)